# How to use a Third-Party DLL in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I have a couple of header files that call functions from DLL files, and I was wondering how I could provide the link for the header files and DLL files to communicate in Visual Studio Code.

Let me know if you need me to elaborate on anything.

Comment: Simply `#include` the DLL header files in your C++ code, and then add the DLL import `.lib` files to your Project.  Or, you can load the DLL functions dynamically at runtime via `GetProcAddress()` if you don't have `.lib` files (though you can easily generate them from the DLLs if needed).

Comment: Would it suffice that the dll and respective header file be located in the same folder essentially?

Comment: They don't need to be, as long as your compiler can find the header files, and your linker can find the import libs.

Comment: To run your application that has dependent dlls they must be in one of the folders listed in your `PATH` environment variable or the same folder as your executable.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio code these are the steps what are needed to use DLL:

1. Create lib file from DLL.

With MinGW it is something like this:

```
dlltool --input-def your_external_lib.def --dllname your_external_lib.dll --output-lib your_external_lib.lib
```

2. modify the tasks.json

   ```
   {
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "your_project_name",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "g++",
           "args": [
               "-g",
               "-o",
               "main",
               "main.cpp",
               "-LC:\\YOUR_LIB_PATH"
               "-lyour_external_lib",
               "-Wall",
               "-Wextra"
           ],
           "group": {
               "kind": "build",
               "isDefault": true
           }
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
3. Add *.hpp and *.h files to your project and build!

Reference: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to access the code defined in Dll. 
Generally all Dll projects we need to provide all the functions that needs to be exported. `__dllexport__`
After we build that DLL project .lib and .dll gets generated, based on all the functions exported.

So when you want to use the member function declared in some header and defined in DLL, you need to follow below steps.

1. in Visual studio, add the .lib generated in Linker-Input-additional
2. Dependencies add the path of linker->general->additional library directories
3. Put the .dll in the path where your .exe is running